# Assert mock arguments if arguments include another mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, monkeypatching

I have a function, for example:

```
def my_function1(my_obj, my_arg):
    # do something
    return
```

In my unittest, I want to test that a second function calls this function with the specified arguments:

```
def my_function2():
    obj1 = SomeClassObject()
    for arg in ["a", "b", "c"]:
        my_function1(obj1, arg)
```

For the test, I have mocked the object, `SomeClassObject`. And I also mock `my_function1` so I can monitor how it is called. So my unittest looks like this:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, call

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("__main__.SomeClassObject", autospec=True)
    @patch("__main__.my_function1")
    def test_my_function2_calls_my_function1(self, mock_function1, mock_class_object):
        my_function2()
        calls = [call(mock_class_object, "a"),
                 call(mock_class_object, "b"),
                 call(mock_class_object, "c")]
        mock_function1.assert_has_calls(calls)
```

But this gives the following error three times:

> AssertionError: (TypeError("missing a required argument: 'my_arg'")

I stepped through using the interactive debugger and I found that the `mock_function1._mock_call_args_list` is

```
[call(<MagicMock name='SomeClassObject' id='140060802853296'>, 'a'),
 call(<MagicMock name='SomeClassObject' id='140060802853296'>, 'b'),
 call(<MagicMock name='SomeClassObject' id='140060802853296'>, 'c')]
```

This is identical to what I get when I print `call(mock_class_object, "a")` etc. The id is exactly the same.
So it looks like when I run `.assert_has_calls` the `MagicMock` object messes things up.

Does anyone know how I can do this correctly?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error when I run the code you supplied In Python 3.6.9. What version of Python are you running? How are you running your tests (i.e. are you using `python -m unittest`, or do you have a `if __name__ == '__main__': unittest.main()` clause at the end)? Please post the exact code that causes your issue.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error on my sample code and also couldn't. After lots of digging I eventually realised my problem was just due to a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why exactly you get that error message, but you test for the class instead of the object as the argument. This is what should work:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch("__main__.SomeClassObject", autospec=True)
    @patch("__main__.my_function1")
    def test_my_function2_calls_my_function1(self, mock_function1, mock_class):
        my_function2()
        mock_class_object = mock_class.return_value
        calls = [call(mock_class_object, "a"),
                 call(mock_class_object, "b"),
                 call(mock_class_object, "c")]
        mock_function1.assert_has_calls(calls)
```

Comment: Yes I noticed the same when working on my sample code. It turned out my problem was due to a typo - I had used square brackets in the `call` function to list the arguments, so of course it couldn't find the second argument. Have some points for the answer though.

Comment: Ah ok, I was wondering about that error message - so that problem was already fixed in the code shown in the question. Thanks for the points :)